# How can I find all the versions of a Unix program on a system?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, version

This came up in coursework, and I'm stuck:

> Many systems have more than one version of a utility program so that users can choose the one they want. Suggest a command to find all the versions of `make` on a system. What determines which one a user actually gets? How might a user override the defaults?

How would you do that?

Comment: What have you tried? You might like to read about the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I have tried to use find / -name make but that didn't seem to work

Comment: `find` as you describe should work. You may being scanning a really giant networked file system. So try restricting what gets searched, ie `find /usr -name '*[Mm][Aa][Kk][Ee]*'` . With the `*`'s in this, you'll get extra output, but it will find thinks like `gmake, cmake, cMake`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How UNIX finds programs

Unix-like systems store their executable programs in various directories for historical reasons.

The directories that are searched when you want to run a command are stored in an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) called `$PATH`, separated by colons (`:`).  To see its contents, type `echo "$PATH"` in a terminal window. On my system, that shows (split to avoid a long line)

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:
/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

They're searched in that order. If I want to run `make`, the system will first check `/usr/local/sbin/make` (which doesn't exist), then `/usr/local/bin/make` (also non-existant), then `/usr/bin/make` (which **does exist**, so it runs that).

## How to figure out which one would run

The program `which` can be used to look through `$PATH` to figure out what program would be chosen. Running `which make` on my system produces the output `/usr/bin/make`.

Conveniently, `which` has a `-a` flag to print *all* executables that match, not just the first one. (I found this by consulting its manual, by running `man which`.) So `which -a java` should tell you where all of the versions of `java` are.

## Changing the defaults

If you like, you can change the contents of the `$PATH` variable, like you can change any environment variable: If I run `PATH="$PATH:/home/anko/bin"`, the next time the system needs to find a program, it will check through all of what `$PATH` used to be, plus a directory called `bin` in my home directory if it couldn't find anything else.

I could also prepend the directory, to make it take precedence over anything else, by doing `PATH="/home/anko/bin:$PATH"`.

Comment: What if the question was  something like this? Many systems have more than one version of a utility program so that users can choose the one they want. Suggest a command to find all the versions @Anko ?

Comment: @Moh `which -a` does that, if they have the same name. If they don't have the same name, you'll have to think of some other criterion that makes them "versions" of each other. (When something is a "different version" and when it's a different thing altogether is kind of a philosophical question… :))